# do_shortcode() within Admin Page

Tags: wp-admin, add-menu-page, shortcode

I'm using a few plugins that have shortcodes ... however, instead of creating a public page for the content, I've created some new pages within the admin using `add_menu_page` and I need to know how to utilize `do_shortcode()` within this context.

As it stands, all the function does it spit out the string. I'm assuming it's because the shortcode API isn't available within an admin page.

How do I get around this? There is no documentation that I can find that explains how to utilize shortcodes within the WP Admin... or if it's even possible.

---

Specifically I'm trying to utilize WooCommerce shortcodes within the WP Admin. I hate the fact that plugins don't utilize the WP Backend for account/user management.

Comment: Whomever came along and decided that "I did not do any research" and gave me a negative score without commenting is extremely unhelpful.

Comment: I guess you could say shortcodes are for front end content ... Are you trying to use another plugin to generate content for your own plugin admin page?

Comment: @dcolumbus I concur. I've seen a few spurious downvotes recently, certainly more than I remember seeing in the past. IMO this is an honest (and pretty awesome) question, so I'm currently taking a stab at an answer ;)

Comment: If you've created an admin page then you can specify the output - why do you need/want to use `do_shortcode()`. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Specially I'm trying to utilize WooCommerce shortcodes. User management and account management pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of calling `do_shortcode()` just call the function associated with the shortcode.

#### Example

There is a shortcode named `[example]` and a function registered as shortcode handler:

```
function example_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    extract( 
            shortcode_atts( 
            array (
            'before' => '',
            'after' => '',
            ), 
            $atts 
       )
   );

    return $before . $content . $after;
}
add_shortcode( 'example', 'example_shortcode' );
```

In your admin page you just call the function:

```
echo example_shortcode( 
    array ( 'before' => 'This ', 'after' => '!' ), 
    'works' 
);
```

Output: `This works!`.

Faster and more reliable than `do_shortcode()`.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of this! Then again, I'd never used shortcodes in the admin (for whatever reason) & had an excuse to investigate ;)

Comment: I have no idea why I haven't thought of this either... I'm going to give it a try and report back!

Comment: One downside to this is that it will break if the plugin author refactors the shortcode's callback function in the future. Changes to the shortcode itself will probably be backwards-compatible, but it's less likely that the plugin's internal function names will be.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the shortcode API *is* available in the admin, but its output will depend on the shortcode tag in question.

The built-in `[caption]` works as expected, whereas `[embed]` doesn't (this is due to how the embed API "lazy-loads" it's shortcode, and depends on `the_content` filter to run, so technically not the shortcode API's fault).

**Conclusion:** It's entirely dependent on how & when the tag is registered, and what it does/assumes when executed.

@dcolumbus Which tag are we talking about in your case?

Comment: Also, some tags will be expecting `get_the_ID()` to return a post ID.