# add php shortcode in return function

Tags: shortcode

I have this part of code:

```
return '<img class="myimage '.$text_color.' '.$horizontal.$slide_fitscreen.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" '.$slide_desc.' />';
```

What I want to do is to return also a php shortcode but not inside the **img** element, because my shortcode generates a **a** element so I need to return it after the img

this is my shortcode:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[daisy]'); ?>
```

I've tried this:

```
return '<img class="myimage '.$text_color.' '.$horizontal.$slide_fitscreen.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" '.$slide_desc.' />'.do_shortcode('[daisy]');
```

but is not working, I receive:

```
Error (Parseerror): Syntax Error Unexpected Token <
```

How can I make this ?
Thanks!
Later edit: here is the entire script:

```
<?php 
function custom_slidessc($atts, $content = null) {

$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
if(strpos($user_agent,'iPhone') || strpos($user_agent,'iPod') || strpos($user_agent,'Android')){ $mobile = true; }else{ $mobile = false; }
$ipad = strpos($user_agent, 'iPad') ? true : false;

$class = shortcode_atts( array('text_color' => '#ffffff', 'image' => '', 'video_vimeo' => '', 'video_youtube' => '', 'video_mp4' => '', 'video_ogg' => '', 'video_webm' => '', 'video_poster' => '', 'slide_desc' => '', 'slide_horizontal' => '', 'slide_fitscreen' => '', 'slide_noresize' => ''), $atts );

    /* Slide Description */
    if($class['slide_desc'] != ''){ 
        $slide_desc = $class['slide_desc']; 
        $slide_desc = "title=\"".$slide_desc."\"";
    }

    /* Slide Text/Cursor Color */
    if($class['text_color'] == '#ffffff'){
        $text_color = 'text_white'; 
    }else{
        $text_color = 'text_black'; 
    }

    /* ------------------------------------*/
    /* -------->>> IMAGE SLIDE <<<---------*/
    /* ------------------------------------*/
    if($class['image'] != ''){
        $image = $class['image'];
        if($class['slide_horizontal'] == 'true'){ $horizontal = 'slide_horizontal '; }else{ $horizontal = ''; }
        if($class['slide_horizontal'] == 'true' || $class['slide_fitscreen'] == 'true'){ $slide_fitscreen = 'slide_fitscreen'; }else{ $slide_fitscreen = ''; }
        return '<img class="myimage '.$text_color.' '.$horizontal.$slide_fitscreen.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" '.$slide_desc.' />';

    /* ------------------------------------*/
    /* ----->>> HTML5 VIDEO SLIDE <<<------*/
    /* ------------------------------------*/
    }elseif(($class['video_mp4'] != '' or $class['video_ogg'] != '' or $class['video_webm'] != '') AND !$mobile){
        $video_mp4 = $class['video_mp4'];
        $video_ogg = $class['video_ogg'];
        $video_webm = $class['video_webm'];
        if($class['video_poster'] != ''){ $video_poster = "poster=\"".$class['video_poster']."\""; }else{ $video_poster = ""; }
        return '<div class="myimage myvideo '.$text_color.'" '.$slide_desc.'>'.do_shortcode('[video mp4="'.$video_mp4.'" ogg="'.$video_ogg.'" webm="'.$video_webm.'" '.$video_poster.' preload="true"]').'</div>';

    /* ------------------------------------*/
    /* ------->>> YOUTUBE SLIDE <<<--------*/
    /* ------------------------------------*/
    }elseif($class['video_youtube'] != ''){
        $video_youtube = $class['video_youtube'];
        if($class['slide_noresize'] = 'true'){ $video_noresize = 'height="360" width="640"'; }else{ $video_noresize = 'height="100%" width="100%"'; }

        $strText = preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', 'link', $video_youtube );
        if($strText == 'link'){
            $array_link_explode = explode('v=', $video_youtube); 
            $array_link_explode = explode('&', $array_link_explode[1]); 
            $video_youtube =$array_link_explode[0];
        }
        $video_poster = $class['video_poster'];

        if($mobile){
            return '<div class="myimage myvideo myvideo_yt '.$text_color.'"  '.$slide_desc.'><div style="height: 100%; width: auto; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;"><iframe style="bottom: 0; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 9999999999;" type="text/html" '.$video_noresize.' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video_youtube.'?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div><img src="'.$video_poster.'" alt="" style="position:absolute;" /></div>';
        }else if($ipad){
            if($video_poster){ $ipad_poster = '<img src="'.$video_poster.'" alt="" style="position:absolute;" />'; }else{ $ipad_poster = ''; }
            return '<div class="myimage myvideo myvideo_yt '.$text_color.'"  '.$slide_desc.' style="height: 100%;"><div style="height: 100%; width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;"><iframe class="youtube-player" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;z-index: 77777777;" type="text/html" '.$video_noresize.' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video_youtube.'?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>'.$ipad_poster.'</div>';
        }else if($video_poster != ''){
            return '<div class="myimage myvideo myvideo_yt '.$text_color.'"  '.$slide_desc.' style="height: 100%;"><div style="height: 100%; width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;"><iframe class="youtube-player" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;z-index: 77777777;" type="text/html" '.$video_noresize.' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video_youtube.'?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><img src="'.$video_poster.'" alt="" style="position:absolute;" /></div>';
        }else if(!$ipad){ //disable fullscreen for ipad
            return '<div class="myimage myvideo myvideo_yt '.$text_color.'" '.$slide_desc.'><iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$video_youtube.'?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';
        }

    /* ------------------------------------*/
    /* -------->>> VIMEO SLIDE <<<---------*/
    /* ------------------------------------*/
    }elseif($class['video_vimeo'] != ''){
        $video_vimeo = $class['video_vimeo'];
        if($class['slide_noresize'] = 'true'){ $video_noresize = 'height="360" width="640"'; }else{ $video_noresize = 'height="100%" width="100%"'; }

        $strText = preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', 'link', $video_vimeo );
        if($strText == 'link'){ 
            $array_link_explode = explode('.com/', $video_vimeo); 
            $video_vimeo = $array_link_explode[1]; 
        }
        $video_poster = $class['video_poster'];

        if($mobile){
            return '<div class="myimage myvideo myvideo_yt '.$text_color.'"  '.$slide_desc.'><div style="height: 100%; width: auto; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;"><iframe style="bottom: 0; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 9999999999;" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$video_vimeo.'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" '.$video_noresize.' frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div><img src="'.$video_poster.'" alt="" style="position:absolute;" /></div>';
        }else if($ipad){
            return '<div class="myimage myvideo myvideo_yt '.$text_color.'"  '.$slide_desc.' style="height: 100%;"><div style="height: 100%; width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;"><iframe style="bottom: 0; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 77777777;" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$video_vimeo.'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" '.$video_noresize.' frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div><img src="'.$video_poster.'" alt="" style="position:absolute;" /></div>';
        }else if($video_poster != ''){
            return '<div class="myimage myvideo myvideo_yt '.$text_color.'"  '.$slide_desc.' style="height: 100%;"><div style="height: 100%; width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;"><iframe style="bottom: 0; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 77777777;" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$video_vimeo.'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" '.$video_noresize.' frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div><img src="'.$video_poster.'" alt="" style="position:absolute;" /></div>';
        }else if(!$ipad){ //disable fullscreen for ipad
            return '<div class="myimage myvideo myvideo_yt '.$text_color.'" '.$slide_desc.'><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$video_vimeo.'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>';
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
add_shortcode("slide", "custom_slidessc");
?>
```

Comment: Can we see your entire (relevant) code?

Comment: At a quick review, there is an issue at line 64 of this code sample ... er, my bad, mixed it up in another test environment. Disregard this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call [`do_shortcode()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/61576/73). Use the associated handler instead.

And if you want to call the shortcode without parameters you have to make the parameters optional in the handler’s declaration:

```
function custom_slidessc($atts = array(), $content = null)
```

So what you need is:

```
return '<img>' . custom_slidessc();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused where should I add the shortcode exactly?

Comment: Where you declare the function is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

`do_shortcode` needs to be echoed for its output to be printed to the screen, so you will need to find a way to work around that. Here is an idea:

```
// Start an output buffer to capture the echo
ob_start();

echo do_shortcode( '[daisy]' );

//Put the output into a usable variable */
$daisy_output = ob_get_contents();

//End the output buffer capture
ob_end_clean();

return '<img class="myimage ' . $text_color . ' ' . $horizontal . $slide_fitscreen . '" src="' . $image . '" alt="" ' . $slide_desc . ' />' . $daisy_output;
```

There may be a better method but at least this should provide a proof-of-concept for the output you are trying to get.

Comment: Unfortunately is not working for me, is very annoying for me because I have the impression that is something simple but my experience with php is basic. However if you want to take a look at the entire script here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B327h/)

Comment: I've updated my post with the entire script