# Echo post title in post

Tags: functions, title

I am looking to echo the post title at the beginning of each post.  I've tried adding the following to `functions.php` with no luck:

```
function add_post_content( $content ) {
    if ( ! is_feed() && ! is_home() ) {
        $content .= '<p>.get_post('post_title').</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

Should I be trying to update the `functions.php` file or `single.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `the_title()`:

```
function add_post_content($content) {

        if(!is_feed() && !is_home()) {

                $content = the_title( '<p>', '</p>', FALSE ) . $content;
        }

        return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

The first two arguments are for `$vefore` and `$after`. If a post doesn’t have a title, you get not extra markup. The last argument makes the function returning the string. Otherwise it would print it out immediately.

Comment: Yeah, this echoes at the end of the post. Otherwise, it works great!

Comment: @GeneMiller See my update. I thought your example code is what you want.

Comment: @toshcho, no problem. Your revision is just what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @toshcho, if I wanted to add some shortcode around that title, would I need to redo the whole function or create two separate functions?

Comment: @GeneMiller Do not use the shortcode, [use the callback](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/do-shortcode-within-admin-page/61576#61576) directly.

Comment: in that thread you say "In your admin page you just call the function:". Can you tell me where exactly in the admin page? Am I editing a specific file?