# Shortcodes (with a space) added to php Sample

Tags: php, shortcode, admin

I have found only a small handful of posts from around the internet regarding Shortcodes and allowing them to work / execute within Admin Pages.

So, I have made several admin pages in Wordpress, and one of them requires me to add a shortcode from one of the other plugins.

I have found this solution which according to the comments *it works*:
[do_shortcode() within Admin Page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/do-shortcode-within-admin-page)

However, the example in the answer uses *[example]* as the shortcode, the shortcode I am trying to use is *[customcont form=3]* If you notice, there is a space in my shortcode which is what puzzled me.

*Because of that I'm now struggling how to incorporate that into the example that is on that thread??*

This is not a duplicate question, I'm asking how to add my shortcode with a space into the example provided.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode. In the example you saw they call the shortcode function directly

Comment: Thank You, however, They are avoiding the do_shortcode in the example I provided... the chosen answer states that and provides an alternative?

Comment: same question with the same answer. shortcodes are for front end you might or might not be able to get what you want by directly calling their core function to generate the info on the admin side

Comment: I reopened your question. And there is now a big **but** here: Remove all that extra **boldness** and the **SHOUTING**. Then edit your title to reflect the "space in shortcode" part. And for future questions: Do **not** SHOUT in questions, comments and answers. Got that?

Comment: I did not intend to shout, i was highlighting the areas that point out it is not a duplicate answer - my bad. Edits done. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there isn't an "space" in the Shortcode-Name. What you have, is an shortcode called "customcont", that is providing an Parameter called "form".

So this is, how it should work:

```
function example_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    extract( 
        shortcode_atts( 
            array (
                'form' => 0,
            ), 
            $atts 
       )
   );

    return 'FORM TO DISPLAY IS #'.$form;
}
add_shortcode( 'customcont', 'example_shortcode' );
```

With the `$form` Variable you can Access the Number of the form to Display, in your case the "3".

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much Lippoliv! I quickly just tried this out and it executes perfectly. Thank You!