# Add shortcode support to custom field

Tags: shortcode, plugins

I'm using CMB2 and I have a wysiwyg field, and I want to display a formiddable form in it by shortcode, but the shortcode is not rendering, but does render in a normal page or post.

How do I enable shortcode rendering on these kind of custom fields?

Comment: [Based on This Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/do-shortcode-within-admin-page) Try calling the shortcode function directly and pass what you need.

Comment: Custom fields is not meant to execute shortcodes or any code for that matter

Comment: The shortcodes library is a wp component that may be used everywhere - wordpress itself just uses it in the_content, but that doesn't mean that you may not use it somewhere else or that they "are not meant" for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Searches content for shortcodes and filters shortcodes through their hooks:

```
echo do_shortcode(
    get_post_meta(
        THE_ID_OF_YOUR_POST, 
        THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD, 
        true
    )
);
```