# Spoof the admin panel on the client side?

Tags: shortcode, templates, admin, sidebar, dashboard

I'm working on some admin dashboards with a plugin that uses shortcodes that are not available in the admin panel (can't use `do_shortcode()` - I tried).  However these are dashboards that I really want to be shown inside the admin panel without having to leave to go to the front end.

I tried at first creating a blank template, placing the shortcodes in a protected front end page and then displaying them in the admin panel via an iFrame (I hated doing it that way but it was the best I could come up with).  Unfortunately, the page doesn't work inside an iFrame and the in page navigation breaks.

So, what I'm thinking now is that I will just leave the protected page in the front end of the site but pull in the admin panel sidebar navigation so that it *looks* like you're still in the backend and my clients will be none the wiser unless they're looking closely at the URL.

Is there a good way to pull in that admin panel sidebar in as a template piece without manually copying and pasting all of the static HTML/CSS?

I know I'll be changing things on the admin sidebar so I would really prefer to keep that dynamic.  Or any other ideas for how to display these front end shortcodes in the admin?  I'm open to any creative solutions :)

Comment: would it not be easier to make the shortcodes work in the dashboard? What you're suggesting sounds much much harder than building the plugin from scratch, and there is no guarantee that if you did this the shortcodes would work as you expected

Comment: If I could get the shortcodes to work in the dashboard that would definitely be preferable, but I haven't found a way to do it.  The dashboards are being built with GravityView and they don't have a native PHP function to build the dashboard.  I tried a lot of things with do_shortcode() but finally figured out that they won't render because the code that makes them render properly only executes on the frontend.  I really am open to other solutions though!  This seems like a weird workaround for sure, but I haven't come up with a better one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [do\_shortcode() within Admin Page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/do-shortcode-within-admin-page). Assuming you're trying to use "GravityViews"'s shortcodes, seems like you should be able to pull in whichever GV PHP library files you need and use the corresponding functions directly

Comment: I had looked into that but it wasn't as simple as that post had made it sound.  I've been working with GravityView's team to try and get this to work within the dashboard and they said, "It's a bit more complicated than that. The extension is hooking itself to the current_screen WordPress hook to check if the request is on the dashboard and if it's a View. Then there's a whole class of functions handling and loading what it is needed."